# Omnet ini configuration file - set random destination for each node

Tags: omnet++, inet

I want to set random destinations for an array of 100 nodes in Udp basic app

```
*.host[*].udpApp[0].destAddresses = "host[${intuniform(0,99)}]"
```

I need to all source nodes to select a random destination and start sending traffic. But omnet++ is giving error in above statement. Already tried
`*.host[*].udpApp[0].destAddresses = "host[${0..99}]"` but it is only selecting first node for all nodes for 1 simulation run.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot achieve your goal this way because according to [OMNeT++ Simulation Manual](https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/manual/#sec:config-sim:referencing-other-iteration-variables) in INI file:

> Variables are substituted textually, and the result is normally not evaluated as an arithmetic expression.

As a matter of fact, the manipulation with the value of `destAddresses` is unnecessary, because UDP Basic App does choose the destination address randomly from the set given in `destAddresses`. Take a look at that method in `UdpBasicApp.cc`:

```
L3Address UdpBasicApp::chooseDestAddr()
{
    int k = intrand(destAddresses.size());
    if (destAddresses[k].isUnspecified() || destAddresses[k].isLinkLocal()) {
        L3AddressResolver().tryResolve(destAddressStr[k].c_str(), destAddresses[k]);
    }
    return destAddresses[k];
}
```

What you should to do is to add all hosts into `destAddresses`. For example, assuming that there are five hosts in the network:

```
*.host[*].udpApp[0].destAddresses = "host[0] host[1] host[2] host[3] host[4]"
```